# How do I combine projects in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, macos

I have a lot of projects in Eclipse and I'm trying to tidy it up with something simple like a folder.  Is there any way to do this so i can have, for example all projects for a particular client in one collapsable folder?

Comment: Have you tried using multiple workspaces - for instance a different workspace for each client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this organization within eclipse without actually changing the filesystem structure of your projects.  The feature, to cut to the chase, is called [Eclipse Working Sets](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcworkset.htm).

The gist is working sets are groups of projects or resources, and most of the eclipse views (package view, enterprise explorer, navigator, etc) can honor and switch between working sets.

Create a working set of type Resource, select the projects you want, then in the package explorer carat drop down (I'm looking at eclipse Kepler) you can either have the top-level elements be the working sets (e.g. a folder-like view per client) or you can filter out stuff one working set at a time.

Some other uses for working sets might be projects of certain types, Java vs. C++ projects, etc. as outlined in this [older tutorial](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/eclipse-working-sets-explained).